# Laravel 5.1. How to add multiple exceptions in 'unique' validation rule?

Tags: validation, laravel-5

For example how to add to exceptions $id1 and $id2 in simple example below?

```
class SomeFormInputRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {   
        $id1 = 1;
        $id2 = 2
        return [
            'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $id1,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make your own validator

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules